# Xubuntu 19.10 Software & Updates app does not work when Python 3.8 is set as default version

Tags: apt, updates, xubuntu, python, software-center

I'm using *Xubuntu 19.10* with default *Python 3* version `3.7.x` and I installed `python3.8` from `ppa:deadsnakes/ppa`. When `python3.8` is configured as default version via `update-alternatives` Xubuntu graphical *Software & Updates* application refuses to start, despite that all `apt` commands work properly from the command line. When I configured back `python3.7` as default version, *Software & Updates* starts to work properly again. How to make it works with `python3.8` set as default?

Comment: @user535733 It seems that `apt` works properly from the command line. Only the graphical tool does not work. If it is true that it is impossible to make the whole system to work properly with `python3.8` set as default via `update-alternatives`, what is the proper way to use the newest Python version on Ubuntu?

Comment: @user535733 10x for the response. If you make it as real response I will accept it.

Comment: It's now a real response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**DON'T DO IT.**

Some essential system services, including apt, are built to work with a specific version of Python 3, and are packaged that way.

**For Ubuntu 19.10**: Those packages for Python 3.8 simply do not exist in the Ubuntu 19.10 repositories. Apt may work with Py 3.8 when Ubuntu 20.04 is released. Ubuntu developers are working to bring Py 3.8 to 20.04. However, that is not a guarantee -- the future is hard to predict.

**The best way to use Py3.8 with Ubuntu 19.10** is to use a virtualization tool like venv or conda. Do NOT try to use apt to install 3.8, as it will remove the existing 3.7 and promptly break your system.